# PEM file to IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, ssl-certificate

I have a PEM file issued by a 3rd party, whose API I'm leveraging.  How can I get this into IIS 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS can't directly import PEM files. Instead you need to convert it to an IIS compatible format, and import that. [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html) will let you do this conversion. The command line would be something like:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -out cert.pfx -name "cert"
```

You could then import cert.pfx into IIS.